# Python скрипт не работает с crontab на macOS

Tags: python, macos, crontab

Всем привет
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что Python скрипт не работает, когда пытаюсь его запустить через crontab.
Что делал я:
1)`crontab -e`
2)`cd /Users/bogdan/Desktop/ && /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3  ./test_bt.py >> /Users/bogdan/Desktop/project_project3.txt 2>&1`
3) НО получаю ошибку в своем текстовом документе: **ERROR: unknown command "./test_bt.py"**

Как мне решить это на оси. Тем более что когда я писал `echo 'Hello' >> файл на раб. столе` , то все работало. А вот с python работать не хочет. Так же права администратора скрипту дал
Скрипт работает нормально, если запускать вручную
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /Users/bogdan/Desktop/ && /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3   /Users/bogdan/Desktop/test_bt.py
```

Почему pip а не python?

Comment: зачем там pip вообще?)

Comment: да. теперь мне не выдает ошибки в создающемся файле.txt. Но скрипт не работает. Нужно ли в нем что то писать кроме когда? Типо #!/usr/local/python???

Comment: мой скрипт должен создавать csv и записывать туда числа для проверки

Comment: pip  это не питон)

Comment: понимаю :( но теперь другая проблема не понимаю, что дальше. Раньше он хотя бы ошибку писал в текстовый. А сейчас ничего не пишет и скрипт не выполняется

Comment: `>> файл на раб. ` добавь

Comment: `cd /Users/bogdan/Desktop/ && /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3   /Users/bogdan/Desktop/test_bt.py >> /Users/bogdan/Desktop/project_project.txt`

Comment: Пишет это: **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/bogdan/Desktop/test_bt.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted**

Comment: Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python а это ещё откуда?

Comment: РАЗОБРАЛСЯ!!!
очень помогла вот эта ссылка: https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/